# Spring Data JPA still trying to generate a query method for a custom implementation

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am currently using Kotlin 1.2 and Spring Boot 2.0 M7 with Spring Data JPA 2.0.2. In here I am trying to create a repository with a custom implementation. My reference is this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Here is the repo

```
interface DailyBuildStatusRepository : BaseRepository<DailyBuildStatus, Int>, DailyBuildStatusCustomRepository {
    
}
```

Here is the interface fragment

```
interface DailyBuildStatusCustomRepository {
    fun filter(product: Int?, branch: Int?,
               correction: Int?, globalSearch: String, isRegEx: Boolean,
               columnParams: Collection<DataTableColumnBean>, start: Int, length: Int): List<DailyBuildStatus>
}
```

Here is the skeleton of the implementing class

```
@Repository
class DailyBuildStatusCustomRepositoryImpl : DailyBuildStatusCustomRepository {
    
    @Autowired
    private val em: EntityManager? = null

    override fun filter(product: Int?, branch: Int?,
                        correction: Int?, globalSearch: String, isRegEx: Boolean,
                        columnParams: Collection<DataTableColumnBean>, start: Int, length: Int): List<DailyBuildStatus> {
        //impl here
    }
}
```

However, upon start up, I see this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.company.srandu.oms.corrviewer.db.repo.custom.DailyBuildStatusCustomRepository.filter(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,boolean,java.util.Collection,int,int)! No property filter found for type DailyBuildStatus!
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type DailyBuildStatus!
```

This was working previously in Spring Data 1.11.9 in Java (Of course the implementing class' name is different as per documentation). Maybe someone has an idea on why this is happening now in Spring 2.0.2?

Comment: Can you file an issue in our JIRA ad attach a sample project?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue by using the code above.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm seeing something like this, although in my case it's a new custom query and on Boot 2.x final, but I'm not sure why it's trying to generate a query when I've supplied an implementation.

Comment: Never mind, I just re-read the section and realized the class name is important. I try to avoid "Impl" suffixes, but in this case, I guess that's critical. :/

Comment: also had that issue, renamed based on the example in the spec and it works now